# If string contains text from list, write matched text to cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I'm working on a large Google spreadsheet with key phrases, strings of text, in column A. I want to search column A based on a list of keywords that live in another sheet. When a keyword matches a word in a string in column A, I want to print that word in an adjacent cell to column A.

Here's a simple spreadsheet to work with that I think demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tNcroABVP0UdP4CiJldxLZgdrJF33TYT4mL1DZJfD1Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to print that word in an adjacent cell to column A

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'KEYWORD LIST'!A2:A)))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Here is the formula with exact match and first letter capitalized. Big thanks!

=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(PROPER(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(LOWER(A2:A10), " ")), LOWER("^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, 'KEYWORD LIST'!A2:A)&"$"))))),,999^99))), " ", ", "))

Comment: One more question...some of my strings have numbers (1,2,3, etc). When the formula is applied to those it returns #VALUE!. How might I allow it to read and print numbers the same as text?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(PROPER(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(IFERROR(SPLIT(LOWER(A2:A10), " "))), LOWER("^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, 'KEYWORD LIST'!A2:A)&"$"))))),,999^99))), " ", ", "))`

Comment: How do I make the formula recognize phrases instead of just a single word? For instance, if my keyword list has the phrase 'dress shoe'. Right now it is recognizing a single word, so I can add the words 'dress' & 'shoe' and then it renders as 'Dress, Shoe' in the cell. But I would like it to just find 'dress shoe' in the list and render 'Dress shoe' in the cell. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (put at B2):

```
=arrayformula(if(ISNUMBER(find(
        transpose({'KEYWORD LIST'!$A$2:$A$6}),A2:A6)), 
        transpose({'KEYWORD LIST'!$A$2:$A$6}),""))
```